# dplyr's filter function: how to return every value (or «cancel» the effect of filter)?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

This may seem like a weird question, but is there a way to pass a value to filter() that basically does nothing?

```
data(cars)
library(dplyr)
cars %>% filter(speed==`magic_value_that_returns_cars?`)
```

And you'd get the whole data frame `cars` back. I'm thinking that this could be useful in a shiny application, where the user would just need to choose the values he wants to filter by; for example the user could choose "Europe", "Africa" or "America" and behind the scenes thet data frame would get filtered and then a table with descriptive statistics for "Europe" would be returned (if the user chose "Europe"). But what if the user wants to have descriptive statistics without first filtering? Is there a value that we could pass to filter to «cancel» filter and pass the whole dataframe to summarise()?

Comment: Easy and exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: Any expression that evaluates to `TRUE` will do. Another example is `cars %>% filter(TRUE)`

Comment: Very nice solution also! But to use this inside a function that uses column names as arguments and then passes it to `filter()` I would need a more general expression, and `filter(speed==speed)` seems to be more general.

Comment: `speed == speed` absolutely is not general. Example with NA in speed: `car = data.frame(num = 1:3, speed = c(1:2, NA)); car %>% filter(speed == speed)`

Comment: Thank you Gregory. It would seem that I need to use an `ifelse` statement then. No biggie!

Comment: @konvas - If you would like to post that answer, I will remove my updated post.  Turns out my answer was incomplete.

Comment: @RichardScriven Thanks but no problem, that's fine if you want to use it in your answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The column will always be equal to itself, so

```
cars %>% filter(speed == speed)
```

will return the full data set.

**Update:** Turns out that won't work when there are `NA` values in the data.  Sorry I missed that.  So, to make this answer correct I will urge you go with the recommendation of @konvas from the comments.

```
cars %>% filter(TRUE)
```

Of course there are other ways, but I think this is the best.

Comment: This soultion doesn't work if there are NA's in the `speed`.

Comment: @GregoryDemin Oops, you are right. I will update in a few hours when I'm back at my computer. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you're applying this in a shiny application, here's an example of how you can filter by "nothing" if for instance, a user selects "All". The combined use of braces and `if` `else` will effectively allow you to skip the line where you apply `filter` to the data set:

```html
x <- "All"

cars %>%
  {if(x!="All") filter(.,speed==x) else .} %>%
  head()

# speed dist
# 1     4    2
# 2     4   10
# 3     7    4
# 4     7   22
# 5     8   16
# 6     9   10

# No data is filtered

x <- 7

cars %>%
{if(x!="All") filter(.,speed==x) else .} %>%
  head()

# speed dist
# 1     7    4
# 2     7   22

# The data is filtered by x==7
```